# Open and run commands in simultaneous windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch file to test IP addresses on the local network of the host. It looks to pull the operating systems of the other machines and write them to a text file.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.1 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv > C:\IP\IP.txt 
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.2 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv >> C:\IP\IP.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.3 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv >> C:\IP\IP.txt
```

(Note: I only show 3 lines here but the actual file runs through all 256 addresses.)

It runs through each line and writes to the file just fine. However if there is nothing at that IP, it takes 30 second to time out and move onto the next IP.

I would like to open a new cmd window for each line and run them simultaneously. Once I have this set up, I'd modify it to only run 10 at a time or something - but I need to reduce the total time it takes to run every line.

I have tried running them with CMD /c (as seen below) but it still seems to wait until each line is complete before moving to the next one. Is there a CMD parameter that I can add to make new window completely independent?

```
CMD /c "FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.1 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv > C:\IP\IP.txt" 
CMD /c "FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.2 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv >> C:\IP\IP.txt"
CMD /c "FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.3 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv >> C:\IP\IP.txt"
```

Comment: I am not sure if this question suits more for server fault. The question is already there: http://serverfault.com/questions/25112/how-to-launch-a-new-cmd-window-from-an-existing-cmd-window

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find it but I never saw that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `START` at te beginning of the line:

```
START CMD /c "FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.1 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv > C:\IP\IP.txt" 
START CMD /c "FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.2 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv >> C:\IP\IP.txt"
START CMD /c "FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i "reply"') DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%g IN ("%%d") DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%h IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%i IN ("%%g") DO FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=." %%j IN ("%%g") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.3 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv >> C:\IP\IP.txt"
...
```

Comment: Quick and easy. thank you. I have some other things to fix now that I have done that but this puts me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `START` command. You may want to escape the double quotes.

```
START "FOR /F ""tokens=1 delims=:"" %%d IN ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1 ^| find /i ""reply""') DO FOR /F ""tokens=3 delims= "" %%g IN (""%%d"") DO FOR /F ""tokens=1 delims=."" %%h IN (""%%g"") DO FOR /F ""tokens=2 delims=."" %%i IN (""%%g"") DO FOR /F ""tokens=3 delims=."" %%j IN (""%%g"") DO WMIC /node:%%h.%%i.%%j.1 os get buildnumber,caption,CSDVersion /format:csv > C:\IP\IP.txt"
```

To make it clean, put the command in a separate batch file and execute it.

```
START "Path\to\batch\file.bat"
```

There are more options available with `START` command. As you may very well know, they can be seen by simply giving the command `START /?`.